# R-Color Tint in openxlsx

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which I order a column from max to least values.  Then using openxlsx, I assign the top 10 values a specific color (say green) in the output spreadsheet. An example follows.

```
library("openxlsx") 
set.seed(123)
test <- data.frame("Name"= letters,"randNum"=runif(26, 1, 100))

test <- test[order(test$randNum,decreasing = TRUE) , ]

wb_test <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb_test, "Sheet", gridLines = TRUE)

Top10Style <- createStyle(bgFill = "#A9D08E")

writeData(wb_test, "Sheet", test)

conditionalFormatting(wb_test, "Sheet", cols = 2,
                                            rows = 2:11, rule = "<101",style = Top10Style,
                                            type = "expression")


saveWorkbook(wb_test, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This produces a column with the top 10 values filled all the same color of green.  What I am trying to do is green tint the colors from rgb(0,255,0,maxColorValue = 255) for the top value to rgb(100,255,100,maxColorValue = 255) for the #10 value.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a colour scale, by setting the `type` to `colourScale`. First we define start and stop value:

```
Top10Style <- c(rgb(0, 255, 0, maxColorValue = 255), 
                rgb(100, 255, 100, maxColorValue = 255))
```

Write the file:

```
wb_test <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb_test, "Sheet", gridLines = TRUE)

writeData(wb_test, "Sheet", test)

conditionalFormatting(wb_test, "Sheet", cols = 2,
                      rows = 2:11, 
                      rule = NULL,
                      style = Top10Style,
                      type = "colourScale")


saveWorkbook(wb_test, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```